# WCF Test client error - There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have configured WcfTestClient.exe as default debug client for my WCF service. This used launch before whenever i hit F5. Now, i am facing this strange error `There is not enough space on the disk error`, when the test client is launched. Below, are the error details.

```
There is not enough space on the disk
```

Comment: Have you answered the most obvious question by yourself: Is there enough space on the disk available?
On the topic: Please check you project folder for any unusual large temp files.

Comment: i have large disk space left on my drives, even i have cleared temp files .. but still the problem persists